# Error in C Program while using pipe symbol

Tags: c, pipe

I am copy pipe symbol as a string in my C program. While compiling its working fine, but while execution I am getting the following error

```
sh: Syntax error: "|" unexpected
```

This is the code:

```
puts("Enter the password");
fgets(buffer, 50, stdin);
strcpy(command, "echo -n ");
strcat(command, buffer);
puts(command);
strcat (command, "| md5sum");
puts(command);
system(command);
```

Basically I am trying to calculate the md5sum for an user input.

Comment: sorry am not strong in c++, let me ask one question? is command is a variable here? what type of value it holds?

Comment: What is the contents of `buffer`? Also, how is `buffer` declared?

Comment: Note that it would be much better to invoke `md5sum` directly via `popen()` rather than using a `system()` kludge.

Comment: buffer is defined char array. this is a c code

Comment: paul can you be give me a sample code. I m new to c

Comment: @SujithKarivelil The question is about C, not C++. Just to be exact.

Comment: @  glglgl that i know, any way thanks for the information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fgets is including the \n (at the end of the user's input) in 'buffer', which is breaking up your command line that you pass to the shell. You will need to remove the \n before composing your command line.

(For any serious work it would be better to use a library call rather than shelling out to  md5sum(1); for instance https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/md5.html .)

Comment: I changed the code like following, but still getting the following error:   Also I am doing this for an assigment. I need to get the value from terminal   strcat(command, buffer);
len = strlen(buffer);
if (buffer[len - 1] == '\n')
buffer[len - 1] = '\0';